# Convert string with meter and centimeters to centimeters

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like `1 M 24 Cm` and I want to convert it to centimeters only.

So instead of `1 M 24 Cm` I want to have `124 cm`

What's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the first digits, representing the meters, and replace up to the start of the `Cm` digits with that captured group, looking ahead for the `Cm` digits and characters:

`(\d+) M (?=\d+ Cm)` replace with `$1`

```
$orig = '1 M 24 Cm';
$replaced = preg_replace(
  '/(\d+) M (?=\d+ Cm)/',
  '$1',
  $orig
);
echo $replaced;
```

or you might lookbehind for a digit, and replace the `M` with the empty string

```
$replaced = preg_replace(
  '/(?<=\d) M (?=\d+ Cm)/',
  '',
  $orig
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be to assert the start of the string `^`, match one or more digits `\d+` and  reset the starting point of the reported match `\K`.

Then match `M` followed by a positive lookahead `(?=` that asserts that what follows is one or more digits followed by `Cm` and assert the end of the string. Replace the match with an empty string and use [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php).

```
$re = '/^\d+\K M (?=\d+ Cm$)/';
$str = '1 M 24 Cm';
$subst = '';
$result = strtolower(preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1));
echo $result; // 124 cm
```